# hr with an image through css

Tags: html, css

I find this a pain. I am trying to get CSS to use an image when the `< hr />` tag is used.
I am currently using:

```
hr
{
  display:block;
  border:none;
  height:10px;
  background-image:url('img/ruler.gif');
}
```

However, I always get a border around the image. As you can see, the `border:none` does nothing.

I know there are alternative ways such as using div. But is it possible through using the hr tag only?

The main users will be using IE6, so need a IE6 compatable solution please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `border:none;` to `border:0;`

Answer (score 15):

```
hr {
    display:block;
    border:0px;
    height:10px;
    background-image:url('img.gif');
}
```