# <hr> tag as an Image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Id like to use a custom .png as a hr line

Here is my image:

[image]

This is the code I wrote, but it doesn't work:

```
hr { 
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:20px;
background:url(../img/bocLine.png);
border:0;
border-color: #000;
}
```

I don't want it to repeat, Just want one in the middle of the page. If it helps in anyway I am using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: Of Course I did! Nothing really came up

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [hr with an image thru css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097095/hr-with-an-image-thru-css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```

a simple google search can find this...

first result of google when searching how to center backgrounds http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Worked Perfect, I never done this before so I wasn't sure what to google, never the less thanks for the help, for the effect I wanted I just got rid of 
    background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: googles your friend you can just use your question terms as a search for example if you search this `<hr> tag as an Image center background` you'll get plenty of results:p

Comment: Haha I guess google is! Never the less thanks and up-voted and marked as correct for you!

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
hr { 
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
height:20px;
background:url(../img/bocLine.png) no-repeat center top; 
border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add no repeat property to your `<hr>` background's CSS.

```
background-image: url(../img/bocLine.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: transparent url(../img/bocLine.png) no-repeat center center;
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need something like this?

```
hr {
    background:url("image.png") no-repeat top center;
    height:42px;
    border:none !important;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/r9usqnc6/1/