# Is it possible to put an image above the <hr> tag in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question regarding images in HTML. Is it possible to add an image above a `<hr>` tag? Because what I want to achieve in my code is to have a an image just above the created `<hr>`. Can someone answer me if this would be possible or not?

[image: This is my page. I want to put an image above that horizontal line.]

I wanted it to look like this: 
[image]

Is this possible? Or maybe someone can give di possible solutions?

Comment: plz add code snippet. thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. But what have you tried to solve that problem? What was you problem? Show a minimal, complete code snippet that illustrates you problem.

Comment: Yes you can please check (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499132/hr-tag-as-an-image/32499182) its already explained .

Comment: please show us your code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and instead use `hr` use `border-bottom` to wrap div also add `justify-content: space-between;` to set the image in end of wrap div (right side)

```css
body,html{
width:100%;
margin: 0;
}
.header{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 15px;
}
img{
width:100px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="left">인사말</div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**화이팅!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I think its useful for you.

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.text-left {
    padding: 35px 0;
}
.bg-section {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span class="text-left">인사말</span>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/SK1J1fR/tire.png" alt="img" class="img-right">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <section class="bg-section"></section>
</div>
```